# Motivation for definition of quotient map and "passing to the quotient"

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm a bit confused by the definition of of a quotient map between topological spaces. What is the reason for constructing a topology in this way? I am familiar with quotients from algebra and even so with the idea of taking the quotient by an equivalence relation, but defining quotient maps in this way seems strange/artificial to me. Especially since I'm used to seeing quotients on the domain, but quotient maps induce the quotient topology on their image.

Also, could someone explain to me "what is going on" when we pass to the quotient? I understand the existence and uniqueness properties from a purely logical point of view but have no intuition on what passing to the quotient is actually achieving. It seems to me like we are constructing a unique continuous function given a quotient space and another continuous function (that satisfies some properties). Is that all? Again, what is the motivation? How are these constructions helpful?

Comment: The motivation for doing it is that we do it all the time.

Comment: That can hardly be any motivation. I find it hard to believe that someone defined these randomly.

Comment: Definitions arise from the observation of what we do: we use definitions to capture useful notions, and they are useful *before* we turn them into  definitions. This is how mathematics is done in real life. The idea that we define things out of some mythical «motivation» is an outgrowth of the way we teach, and of a mistaken and quite damaging image that mathematics has outside of its circle of practitioners (in great part due to the fault of some of its practitioners, alas)

Comment: Nowadays students are presented with a definition of what a group is and *then* examples and motivations, while in real life people had been using groups and being motivated looooong before anyone thought to define what a group is. Successful definitions were, in history, successful because they captured a notion that had already been in the minds of mathematicians, and for which they felt ---usually after the fact--- a need.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. My question was why quotient maps are defined in the way they are. Clearly, the definition is trying to capture some useful or important property. I am merely wondering which ones and how this definition achieves doing so.

Comment: Well, once you come to accept that, then a good plan is to wait a bit, and see for what the notion is used. Soon you will see the notion at play in various contexts, and you'll not need anymore to be given a motivation for it for you'll have seen it yourself: to do what you will be doing. The way we teach math these days requires a generous dose of "suspension of disbelief" on the part of the student. An abstract explanation of what "passing to the quotient" is is worth 0.0000000000% of actually seeing it done in a real life context, when the need for it arises *for you*.

Comment: Constructing a set/group/topological space/etc  by carrying out identifications on another set/group/topological spac/etc is one of the (very few!) ways in which mathematicians construct things. The definition of *quotient map* captures the good situation of that procedure in the case of topological spaces. Of course, this probably means nothing to you — explaining it in the abstract is akin to trying to explain to someone what chocolate icecream tastes like using textmessages.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez : Mario, is this technique used in areas of Math other than Algebraic Topology?

Comment: @MSIS: If you are asking about the technique of "suspension of disbelief", I'll say it is used almost every day by every mathematician. Whenever you *apply* a theorem, you are suspending any disbelief you might have in that theorem, and you are doing this for a very practical reason: you can't reprove a theorem every time you re-apply it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The definition of a quotient map is not very enlightening, in my opinion. The intuition behind $X/\sim$ is "crushing the equivalence classes to points" inside of $X$. This is best seen through some examples:

The interval $[0,1]$ with the relation $0\sim 1$ gives the quotient $[0,1]/\{0,1\} \cong S^1$, the circle.

More generally, $D^n/\partial D^n \cong S^n$, where $D^n$ is the closed $n$-disk and $S^n$ is the $n$-sphere.

But how does this relate to the technical definition? First, $X/\sim$ as a set should not distinguish between two points in the same equivalence class. Thus, it's natural to take $X/\sim$ as the set of equivalence classes.

As for the topology, for the quotient $f: X\to X/\sim$ to be continuous, we must require that for any open set $U\subset X/\sim$, we have $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. But we want the topology of $X$ to entirely determine the topology of its quotient, so it's natural to define the open sets of $X/\sim$ to be *precisely* the subsets with open preimage in $X$. Thus, we recover the definition.

Edit: Now, what do we mean by "passing to the quotient"? This is relatively easy to understand if we think of the quotient space $X/\sim$ as crushing the equivalence classes to points: If we have a continuous map $f: X \to Y$ (for some arbitrary space $Y$) that is constant on some equivalence class $S$ (say $f$ maps points in $S$ to the point $y\in Y$), then we can think of $f$ mapping the entire equivalence class $S$ to $y$. Hence, we can see $f$ as a map on the quotient $f:X/\sim \to Y$ where $f$ maps the equivalence class $S$ to $y$. If $f$ is constant on each equivalence class, this gives a well-defined mapping, so $f$ "passes" or "descends" to the quotient.

Comment: This is just a great answer. It captures the fact that such things are defined with a particular purpose in mind, not handed down on stone tablets from the mountaintop. Once you ask "What topology would $X/~$ have to have for $f$ to be continuous?" you're sorta led by the nose to the right answer.

Comment: This is enlightening indeed. What can we say about the meaning of passing to the quotient?

Comment: I edited in an explanation about passing to the quotient. I hope it's helpful!

Comment: Yes, it was. Thank you.

Comment: This is a good answer. I was completely baffled by the Universal Property of Quotient maps (i.e. passing to the quotient) when I first seen it. Then one day I was reading something that related to this and realized I should think of passing to the quotient in this way and suddenly it all became clear.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N < G$  represent that  the subgroup) $N$ is normal in $G$.
Then we use one of the theorems on Homomorphisms ( i.e, we're dealing with Algebra here )
that given a homomorphism $h$ between groups $G,G'$ , and $N$ normal in $G;N'$normal in $G'$   , then when $h: G \rightarrow G'$ passes to the quotient (i.e., when it's constant on cosets), i.e., it's constant in equivalence classes, we get the induced map $h_*$

$h_*  G/N \rightarrow G'/N'$

$[Ng] \rightarrow [h(Ng)]$

i.e., the class/coset of $g$ in $G/N$ is sent to the class of $h[gN ]$ ; the class of
the image under $h$.

Specifically , in our case, we're dealing with quotients in(Co)Homology Vector Spaces. The groups involved (Cycles, Boundaries) are Abelian, so that every subgroup is normal in the group. Quotients are cosets consisting of (Co) Homology classes . Then a class in G/N (Cycles, Boundaries) is sent to the class of it's image under the map.